# TDD practice: Distinguishing between genuine failures and unimplemented features

Tags: python, tdd

If you are in the middle of a TDD iteration, how do you know which tests fail because the existing code is genuinely incorrect and which fail because either the test itself or the features haven't been implemented yet?  Please don't say, "you just don't care, because you have to fix both."  I'm ready to move past that mindset.

My general practice for writing tests is as follows:

- First, I architect the general structure of the test suite, in whole or in part.  That is - I go through and write only the names of tests, reminding me of the features that I intend to implement.  I typically (at least in python) simply start with each testing having only one line: self.fail().  This way, I can ride a stream of consciousness through listing every feature I think I will want to test - say, 11 tests at a time.
- Second, I pick one test and actually write the test logic.
- Third, I run the test runner and see 11 failures - 10 that simply self.fail() and 1 that is a genuine AssertionError.
- Fourth, I write the code that causes my test to pass.
- Fifth, I run the test runner and see 1 pass and 10 failures.
- Sixth, I go to step 2.

Ideally, instead of seeing tests in terms of passes, failures, and exceptions, I'd like to have a fourth possibility: NotImplemented.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: This belongs on programmers.se

Comment: Writing lots of unit tests before getting any of them to pass is a massive TDD *anti*-pattern - so the "best practice" is "don't do that". It's very easy to interpret the test results when all the tests are passing. As you've found out, it's not at all easy to interpret the test results when lots of tests are failing. (Note: I'm not a Python developer, but I've done a **lot** of TDD in other languages.)

Comment: What's the best pattern then?  Thinking of a feature and writing a test for it right on the spot?  If that were the only acceptable TDD pattern, I'd reject TDD entirely.  I value being able to stream out large numbers of future units in the form of test names and then going and writing the meat of the tests one at a time.  This is a very mainstream approach, at least in the django community.  Use of the @expectedFailure decorator, however, is not AFAIK.

Comment: In general, the best practice is to do as much thinking as one feels appropriate - but only to write one **unit** test at a time. Acceptance tests, such as are common in Behavior-Driven Development, are a different story (and are typically written in a different test suite, if not a completely different tool). However, lots of not-passing **unit** tests make life much more difficult when it comes to determining whether or not one's most recent change broke something unexpectedly. The fix is to not have lots of failing unit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of TDD tools have the idea of PENDING tests vs FAILING tests. I think `unittest2` makes this distinction too.

(I think how you do this is write:

```
def test_this_thing(self):
  pass
```

... but this is from memory...

[EDIT: In 2.7's unittest, or unittest2, you can mark test with the `@skip`, or `@unittest.expectedFailure` decorator. [See the documentation on this](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures)

Comment: I'd love to know more about this.  It's not obvious from the unittest2 docs.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a pointer to the documentation on how to do this. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I use a piece of paper to create a test list (scratchpad to keep track of tests so that I don't miss out on them). I hope you're not writing all the failing tests at one go (because that can cause some amount of thrashing as new knowledge comes in with each Red-Green-Refactor cycle).

To mark a test as TO-DO or Not implemented, you could also mark the test with the equivalent of a `[Ignore("PENDING")]` or `[Ignore("TODO")]`. NUnit for example would so such tests as yellow instead of failed. So Red implies test failure, Yellow implies TODO.

Answer (score 1):

Most projects would have a hierarchy (e.g. project->package->module->class) and if you can selectively run tests for any item on any of the levels or if your report covers these parts in detail you can see the statuses quite clearly. Most of the time, when an entire package or class fails, it's because it hasn't been implemented.

Also, In many test frameworks you can disable individual test cases by removing annotation/decoration from or renaming a method/function that performs a test. This has the disadvantage of not showing you the implementation progress, though if you decide on a fixed and specific prefix you can probably grep that info out of your test source tree quite easily.

Having said that, I would welcome a test framework that does make this distinction and has NOT_IMPLEMENTED in addition to the more standard test case status codes like PASS, WARNING and FAILED. I guess some might have it.

Answer (score 0):

I also now realize that the unittest.expectedFailure decorator accomplishes functionality congruent with my needs.  I had always thought that this decorator was more for tests that require certain environmental conditions that might not exist in the production environment where the test is being run, but it actually makes sense in this scenario too.

Comment: I'm actually very happy with this solution.  I'm marking it correct unless there are any major objections.